# store value do not change ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have the following structure

```
export interface MyStructure {
  id: string
  values: Array<MyObject>
}
```

In my store I have an action that call the following

```
const ADD_OBJECT= (state: State, action: featureAction.AddObject) => {
  const vals= state.entities[action.payload.objId].values;
  vals.concat(action.payload.newObj);
  return featureAdapter.updateOne({
    id: action.payload.routeId,
    changes: {
      waypoints : [...vals]
    },
  }, state);
};
```

but this never update my store...

I also tried

```
    changes: {
      waypoints : new Array<MyObject>
    }
```

the only way I made it work was

```
const ADD_OBJECT= (state: State, action: featureAction.AddObject) => {
  const obj = {...state.entities[action.payload.objId]};
  obj.values= [...obj .values, ...[action.payload.newObj]];
  return featureAdapter.updateOne({
    id: action.payload.objId,
    changes: obj ,
  }, state);
};
```

but this is overkill as everything is renewedm can't I just update the array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable `vals` here `const vals= state.entities[action.payload.objId].values;` references to the object from State. So `vals.concat(action.payload.newObj);` mutates that Object.

**You should not mutate State**.

And this `const obj = {...state.entities[action.payload.objId]};` works because [spreed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) creates a new Object (a new reference). Then NgRx will capture reference change and update the State.

Comment: yes my bad just realized, I thougt a new ref from inside the object would still trigger some change

Comment: Every Object has its reference - even those are properties of other Object. You could also use lodash or something else to clone deep if that is really necessary